# navigate in a loadchildren path doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, nativescript, lazy-loading

I have a pretty simple project setup but my navigation to a lazy loaded path with loadchildren is not working...

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes= [
    {path:'', redirectTo: 'auth', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path:'auth', component: AnmeldungComponent},
    {path:'system', loadChildren: '~/app/system/system.module#SystemModule'},
    {path:'settings', component: SettingsComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

system-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: ListeSystemComponent,

    },
    { path: "monitorliste", component: ListeMonitorComponent },
    { path: "messwerte/:id", component: DatenMonitordatenComponent },
    {
        path:
            "messwertverlauf/:schwelleAlert/:schwelleGut/:schwelleWarn/:schwelleRichtung/:id",
        component: MesswertverlaufComponent,
    },

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule],
})
export class SystemRoutingModule {}
```

list-monitor.component.ts:

```
onItemTap(currentMonitorListeElem: MonitorListeElem){
    this.routerExt.navigate(['messwerte',currentMonitorListeElem.id ], {transition: {name: 'slideLeft'}, relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

when executing the `onItemTap` function i get the error:
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'system/monitorliste/messwerte/421'

isn't it exactly the right route or what do I understand totaly wrong?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
edited system-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: ListeSystemComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: "monitorliste",
                component: ListeMonitorComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "messwerte/:id",
                        component: DatenMonitordatenComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path:
                            "messwertverlauf/:schwelleAlert/:schwelleGut/:schwelleWarn/:schwelleRichtung/:id",
                        component: MesswertverlaufComponent,
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

when I use it like this, i can't even reach "monitorliste" and I am stuck in "system"

When using this:
system-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: ListeSystemComponent,

    },
    {
        path: "monitorliste",
        component: ListeMonitorComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: "messwerte/:id",
                component: DatenMonitordatenComponent,
            },
            {
                path:
                    "messwertverlauf/:schwelleAlert/:schwelleGut/:schwelleWarn/:schwelleRichtung/:id",
                component: MesswertverlaufComponent,
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

I can reach "monitorliste" but I can't reach "messwerte/:id" instead i get redirected to "monitorliste"

Comment: In Angular 8 lazy loading changes: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules (anyway, in Angular 7 I think that you need use the dot ., nor the ~

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that "messwerte/:id" is not a child of "monitorliste" and you get an error "Cannot match any routes".

```
{
  path: "monitorliste",
  component: ListeMonitorComponent,
  children: [{ path: "messwerte/:id", component: DatenMonitordatenComponent }]
},
```

Also notice, that new method for lazy loading available, e.g.

```
loadChildren: () => import('./crm/crm.module').then(m => m.CrmModule)
```

Comment: So I understood the concept wrong? I thought when implemented as I did, it loads all routes of the `system-routing.module.ts` lazily. and so I can use children routes to delay the time when they are loaded to the point when they are clicked/called.
but you suggest to set childrens "one level deeper". (messwert/:id as child of monitorliste)
This would explain why it is not working when i use the edited `system-routing.module.ts`
can you have a look whether my idea is right or wrong?